# Can you search an array by keyword?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How do you take an array like `["foo",1,2,3]` and turn it into something that can quickly be searched by keyword `"foo"`?

I'm trying to take a csv file, and sort/filter it based on a condition. For example, given the following csv and criteria:

```
foo,bar,foobar
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

@criteria = ["foobar", "foo"]
```

the output should be the following (order is important):

```
foobar,foo
3,1
6,4
9,7
```

I'm using a nested loop to check every item in `@criteria` against every `index[0]` of the csv.

```
require 'csv'

@criteria = ["foobar", "foo"]
@newcsv = []
csv = CSV.read("./foo.csv", { headers: true, return_headers: false })
csv = csv.to_a.transpose
@criteria.each do |n|
  csv.each do |i|
    if i[0] == n
      @newcsv.push(i)
      end
  end
end
@newcsv = @newcsv.transpose
CSV.open("./transpose.csv", "wb") do |lines|
  @newcsv.each { |line| lines << line }
end
```

It works on small matrices, but I'm sure it won't scale. I'm wondering if a hash might give me better performance. How can I only get the rows in `@criteria` without using a nested loop?

Comment: If Ruby has a good map implementation, and assuming the array is small enough easily to fit in memory, I would implement this as a map from each column header to an array containing the column values by row.  Then it's easy to select and sort the columns.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't think that you ***can*** improve operations over matrices much. By their nature, matrix operations tends to have at least `Omega(n^2)` runtime behavior. If you're trying to "sort by name", why does "foobar" come before "foo" in your example? By the way, which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: There are 2 applications that parse csv files. Both applications require the columns in a specific (non uniform) order. Running ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So **this answer was posted by another user** and later deleted because he or she "hated it", but I think it at least adds some useful information to the original poster, so I'm reposting it here.

Note that I'm not sure if this code has asymptotic performance that's faster than `O(n^2)` for an `n * n` matrix, but the original author disagreed with me. Here, at least, is my reasoning:

- If you have an `n * n` matrix, and you have `n - 1` criteria, then wouldn't creating indices take in the worst-case `n-1 + n-2 + .. + 2 + 1 = O(n^2)` steps, depending on how the criteria and columns of the matrix are sorted?
- And then you still end up needing to collect `n(n - 1)` cells, even if it is by constant-time array index access.

That was my reasoning at least. Maybe I am wrong. If I am, please explain how so, and what the correct asymptotic runtime complexity of the code below is!

### Answer from Original Author

Scanning an array for an element is inefficient, but once you have an index, looking up for an element at that index is fast.

Given the header line `header = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]` and `@criteria = ["foobar", "foo"]`, you can convert them into `indices`:

```
indices = @criteria.map{|column| header.index(column)}
# => [2, 0]
```

Then, using `indices`, you can map the rows:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]
.map{|row| row.values_at(*indices)}
```

which gives:

```
[
  [3, 1],
  [6, 4],
  [9, 7],
]
```

This way, majority of the computational complexity lies in creating `indices`, which is done only once and the time spent on it is ignorable, and all the rest is element look up by index, and the complexity is small, unlike what a user comments.

Here is some example code using the above methods:

```
require 'csv'

@criteria = ['foobar', 'foo']

table = CSV.read('./foo.csv', headers: true)
indices = @criteria.map { |column| table.headers.index(column) }
table.map { |row| row.values_at(*indices) }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why they deleted it, because this is exactly what worked! https://github.com/spuder/simple-ynab